# How can I add button in Flutter local notification in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, flutter-local-notification

I have Flutter app and I'm using a flutter local notification. I need to add a "snooze" button and functionality to redirect to the home screen to select the user's expected time.

Or is there any other way to know the snooze button in users device
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this problem can't fix in flutter code. because this is android Specific action and this action run  in native background working.

Comment: Thank you, but in some apps can able tap snooze icon, any other notification settings to enable and  then  know if the user tapping or not